# How to change the colour of an imported shapefile in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, ndvi, css

I'm brand new to this website and coding. I'm using GEE to display NDVI with different classes of forest gain and loss. So I've imported a zip folder of shapefiles for my AOI, but how do I make the shapefiles the same colour as my NDVI classification product? I found a code that works but the default colour is red (I changed it to white). I've re-added a sample of AOI coordinates to show you how I want the rest of the shapefile to look.

I'll only paste a small sample of the code because it's quite long, you can find the rest here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f644d0c1e5f737a3ee01f1df601d3f17

This is the code I found. So how could I display my AOI shapefiles as the same palette listed further in my code?

```
//Display the shapefile into the interactive map
Map.addLayer(AOI);
//Display the view to the center of the screen and scale the view
Map.centerObject(AOI); 
//Define styling and determine the color of the shapefile 
var styling = {color: 'white', fillColor: 'ffffff'};
Map.addLayer(AOI.style(styling));

//  Palette with the colors
var palette =['ff1b1b', 'ffa81b', 'f5ff1b', '1bff2f', '099b16', 'ffffff'];
// name of the legend
//var names = ['Forest Gain (high probability)','Forest Gain, Low','unchanged', 'Forest loss', 
'Forest loss (high probability)', 'NA'];
var names = ['Forest loss (high probability)', 'Forest loss', 'unchanged', 'Forest Gain, Low', 
'Forest Gain (high probability)'];
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to share the table.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/muraj012/Plantation_Forests_AOI Hi! this link should work. BTW - I have read several of your articles for my research! Thanks for replying!

Comment: Update: I actually found a better shapefile to use for my AOI and it works much better. https://code.earthengine.google.com/492946a3e18e4ed3799c1c18ff8aa51c?asset=users%2Fspeterstum%2FOFO_2016_2020_S2_swath

Comment: You want to display the multicolored classified results mapped onto the polygons?  Each polygon can only be a single color.  Are you hoping to break the region up into a bunch of smaller polygons or something?

Comment: I have edited my post to show how it looks now, I found a way to change the shapefile to match the classes.